# JBullet - Shoving around objects

Tags: java, physics-engine, bullet-physics

Sometimes in video games the players can walk up to certain objects for example boxes and barrels and shove them around.

How can I recreate this system? What function do I have to use to apply force in the direction I want, and make the object fall over, rotate etc... ?

Here is an example of what I want to achive:
https://youtu.be/dVr2BUg_oes?si=BdZ6rtGNZ0loGnnN

https://youtu.be/eqH70ytL4Fs?si=HacUvbzPxvj5j1jl

Comment: Are you looking for how to provide force and push a box or barrel [one space at a time](https://youtu.be/nRM8p2re_cY?t=61), or are you looking for a mechanism to push something so that it continues until it hits an edge, similar to an [Ice Block Puzzle](https://youtu.be/eh4ETYvgjuk?t=23)?

Comment: I want to do something like this:https://youtu.be/dVr2BUg_oes?si=BdZ6rtGNZ0loGnnN or this https://youtu.be/eqH70ytL4Fs?si=HacUvbzPxvj5j1jl

Comment: Ah, after a bit of searching, while I don't *know* that this will solve the issue, I might recommend trying to add the "Box" or "Barrel" Rigid Body to the player entity when picking it up, then applying force vial the RigidBodyConstructionInfo with the related details - basing that on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927654/jbullet-example) - though this may be incorrect for that library (Unfortunately, was having issues tracking it down their documentation, and haven't used it personally myself.).